# Почему не работает cURL в php

Tags: php, curl

Код выглядит так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@' . 'img/image.png'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что он не работает?

Comment: Нет ответа от api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, проблема связана с тем, что cURL не оправляет файл. Ниже, варианты ее решения.

## Вариант 1

Для *php >=5.6*, включите поддержку префикса @ для загружаемых файлов в *CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS*.

Для этого нужно указать опцию *CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD*.

Начиная с версии *php 5.6*, эта опция по умолчанию - *TRUE* (выключено):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@' . 'img/image.png'));
```

## Вариант 2

Для *php >=5.5, 7* используйте объект [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) (начиная с версии php7 опция *CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD* удалена):

```
$image = new CURLFile('img/image.png');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => $image);
```